# Keberos cannot access internal URLs

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication, kerberos

I've activated Kerberos on my environment and it seems to be working fine for accessing the website using it's dns name:

http://myintranet.mycompany.com

I cannot however access sites anymore using the server name `http://server01:5011`

My SPNs are setup as :

```
- http/server01:5011 
- http/server01.mycompany.com:5011   
- myintranet.mycompany.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I fixed this by adding additional SPNs for that server by not specifying the port.
If anyone else faces this problem, it is documented in the Microsoft documentation on how to setup Kerberos for SharePoint.

It is a bug that SPN tickets are not correctly formed for Non default Ports. So the answer, is to add a SPN without a port number for those servers.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us

Can´t see, if you do not reach the site, or can´t get authentication.

Comment: This is not the solution for me. Specifically this part in the article is different from my solution: Note You only receive this error message if you try to browse the Web site directly on the server. If you browse the Web site from a client computer, the Web site works as expected.

Comment: My issue occurs if I browse from a client machine OR browsing directly on the server.